# How to transfer multiple data from autocomplete (JQuery UI) to an array via a div-container?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I need an advice how to do that:

The user can select some items via autocomplete (JQuery UI) and put that item to a div-container:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**PHP:**

```
$result = $paed_db->prepare('SELECT id, data FROM table');
$result->execute();
$a_json = array();
while($data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $a_json_row["id"] = $data->id;        
    $a_json_row["value"] = $data->data;
    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}

$json = json_encode($a_json);
print $json;
exit;
```

**JS:**

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/script.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var selecteditem= ui.item.id;
        $('#output').append(selecteditem);
    }
});
```

After that I want to do some further processing with all items, which are in the #output-container via AJAX/SQL:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN ($in);
```

I need that to make some statistics for all items the user had selected (and put to the output container).

So this is my problem: In what way should I put the selected result of the autocomplete in the output container? I'm asking because I have to transfer the ID (which is later beeing used in the SQL) and the text (data) for the user display.

How do I get those informations from the autocomplete to the later array for the SQL-Query?

Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, for every selection with your autocomplete, you will need to create a hidden input field and add it to the output div. this input will have the id of your item as the value.
example of output div:

```
<form action="res.php">
  <div id="output">
    <div> <!-- div used for displaying info only -->
       Here i display some info ...
      <input name="ids[]" value="1">
    </div>
    <div>
      Here i display some info of this item
      <input name="ids[]" value="5">
    </div>
    <div>
      Here i display some info
      <input name="ids[]" value="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

All the inner divs will be generated dynamically here:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/script.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var selecteditem= ui.item.id;
        var $newInput = $("input").attr("type","hidden").
                                   attr("name","ids[]").
                                   attr("value",selectedItem);
        var $newDiv = $("div").append($newInput);
        $('#output').append($newDiv);
    }
});
```

And for receive this values on the php file:

```
$ids = $_POST['ids'];
$list_ids = implode(',', $ids);
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($list_ids);");
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. I used div-container with data attributes instead of input fields, so I don't need a form at all.